# logged users shows as System account in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath, forms-authentication

We have a major problem with one of our applicaiton in SharePoint 2010.

All users who are logged in on the site are displayed as system account (SharePoint \ system).

It happens only with one Website. I've already verify that the farm administrator account It is not used as an AppPool identity for this Web application.

We have a form that uses the current logged user field to send an email to the logged users. Because of that problem ,the system were not able to send the email to the right person.

Can someone help?

Comment: If users click SharePoint\system > About Me to access my site site collection, which account is displayed?

Comment: It's probably the result of a customization.

Comment: @Max576_MSFT Thanks for the reply. It shows the correct user not the SharePoint\sytem account.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. I had a workflow that should start automatically when a new item is created on my library. For some reason I found out that this workflow was checked to get started only when a change has occurred on the items.

In this workflow there’s a rule that assigns the value of the field Modify by  to another field. Then I was using this information to send an email to that user. Because the workflow hasn’t started when a new item is created, so SharePoint assigned automatically the value of the system to the field.

Thank you a lot for your answers.

Comment: It should affect the Modify By field. So it affects the display name in welcome panel as well?